# Mazda 323 2003 astina radiator fan not working

Tags: mazda, fan, astina-323

Having problem with the cooling fan, when car start fan won't turn on. I been researching online, people have suggested replacing the coolant temperature sensor and some suggest the temp gauge sensor (guessing that is the switch?)
I am not sure where they all located. Any suggestion would be great.

jas

Comment: Does the fan(s) turn on when you switch on the AC?

Comment: The fan won't turn on at startup unless the car is already warm and needs to maintain temperature. Is the car overheating? Does it come on after you've warmed the car up?

Comment: No fan won't turn on with the AC. The car is overheating.